# images and form problems in a div

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a div in the size of 900x30

I have a form in this div, but when I try to put an image after the < / form > (the image is still inside the same div as the form), I see the image on a new line.

How can i prevnt it and make the image show in the same line as the form ?

im using CSS btw...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might try `white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to float the image to the left or right:

```
.myDiv img {
    float: right;
}
```

If you post your markup it'll be easier for someone to give a more accurate answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the display attribute of both form and image to 'inline', just in case it's doing a block display?